# How to signal out an overlap among date ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Have no idea how to solve the following problem:

In a given sheet where column "A" is the starting date (month/day/year), "B" is the ending date and "C" is the description, any date range overlap among rows should be signaled out in column "D".

The resulting table should look like this:

| # | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 | Task1 | Row3 |
| 2 | 01/15/2022 | 02/15/2022 | Task2 |  |
| 3 | 01/29/2022 | 02/03/2022 | Task1 | Row1, Row3 |
| 4 | 01/18/2022 | 02/22/2022 | Task3 |  |
| 5 | 02/02/2022 | 02/15/2022 | Task1 | Row3 |

[Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQVxs1iNpnvDTeayQz55KeOBL0V5riDQlp4GwirzwJs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: please check the solution, and if it meets your requirements then mark as the Accepted Solution so that others know it is suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates cross over `IF(($A1<=$B$1:$B$5)*($B1>=$A$1:$A$5)`

and if the Task is the same `($C1=$C$1:$C$5)`

but not if the row is the same `IF(ROW($A$1:$A$5)=ROW(),""`

then return the Row # `"Row"&ROW($A$1:$A$5)`

Complete formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(($A1<=$B$1:$B$5)*($B1>=$A$1:$A$5)*($C1=$C$1:$C$5),IF(ROW($A$1:$A$5)=ROW(),"","Row"&ROW($A$1:$A$5)),"")))
```

Comment: Works great as a drag down formula! Any chance to make this a real arrayformula?